# Delphi: Арабская вязь

Tags: delphi

Как в мемо/ричэдит выводить арабскую вязь?

Вместо неё выводится что-то типа *\u0639\u0644\u0649*

Comment: А есть ли у вас нужные шрифты?

Answer (score 4):

Нужны либо компоненты либо делфи с поддержкой юникода (например компоненты тмс либо `delphi xe2`)